# Is it correct to say "pile of blood"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

What I want to say is that there is a small puddle of blood but find myself using the term too often and want to try something different.

A [quick search of the term on books.google](https://www.google.co.in/search?tbm=bks&q=%22pile%20of%20blood%22&oq=%22pile%20of%20blood%22) does return a few results using that exact phrase but I want to be sure that the term is correct in use.

Comment: The usual online references are sadly lacking in synonyms for "puddle" -- the definitions/synonyms tend toward pool or pond rather than what any 4-year-old would call a puddle.

Comment: a pile of blood and guts, body parts ...

Comment: Maybe you should stay away from knives.  In creative writing, slightly unexpected turns of phrase are welcomed.  If you're writing crime scene reports, maybe stay away from artistic flourishes.

Comment: Rather than the particular words, could you look why you want to say  there is a small puddle of blood "too often."

"… pile of blood" could work if you had the poetic skill. Otherwise, it would always look wrong.

Either way, how is this not a Question on personal style or literary criticism?

Comment: liquid stuff cannot be described as occurring in piles.

Comment: To augment the comment by @Lambie, pure liquids cannot sustain a shear stress; their [angle of repose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_repose) is essentially zero. Therefore, they cannot pile up.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Now, I know how to say it right. ha ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pile of blood" doesn't sound great to my ears. You usually have piles of solid things, like books or leaves. However, some native speakers do say ["pile of blood"](http://www.foxnews.com/us/2018/02/14/saw-big-pile-blood-students-describe-florida-high-school-shooting.html).

If you want a different term, try "pool of blood". This is the most common collocation there is according to my [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) search for `_nn* of blood_nn*`, which finds any noun followed by "of", followed by "blood" as a noun. If we include the plural ("pools"), there are 408 hits total.

In comparison, "pile(s) of blood" only had 4 hits, half of which were for "pile of blood and [something solid]".

Comment: Urghhh. I hate hits. :) Pool, puddle, splotch, splatter and probably many more.

Answer (score 1):

In his article [Collocations with nominal quantifiers: Semantics and combinability](https://hal-univ-tlse2.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00955183/document), Vladimir Beliakov does not mention 'pile of blood' as a collocation, though he does mention the mainly abstract examples

> ‘a pile of questions, a pile of news, a pile of string, a pile of
>   lies, a pile of problems, a pile of meanness, a pile of cowardice, a
>   pile of weakness’

as well as some obvious physical examples

> (‘a pile of laundry ... a pile of snow, a pile of leaves, a pile of
>   papers, a pile of rags’).

He goes on to say that

> [T]he combinability of the words ... ‘heap’, ‘armful’, ‘pile’, and
>   ‘stack’ with [non-abstract] object nouns is semantically motivated, as conditioned by
>   the quantifiers’ semantic concordance with their arguments. Thus
>   ‘pile’ is combined with nouns of objects that are easily moved [and
>   one would argue not fluids]. [Russian equivalents removed.]

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to say is that there is a small puddle of blood but find myself using the term too often and want to try something different.

If you operated a blood bank, and had three or more bags of blood lying in a heap somewhere, you surely could call it a pile of blood. But it wouldn't normally apply to a small puddle of it. So, in the absence of specific context, this sounds more like **bloodshed**.

- Oh dear, more **bloodshed**.